# ASP.NET Backend for Native Mobile Application

Tags: android, ios, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for a little top/level guidance. I don't expect a solution to the problems at hand. My goal is to create a native mobile application (not web) for iOS and Android. I want the content to be served from an in-house Microsoft Server, not a cloud based service like Azure. The mobile clients need to be able to login and make authorized read and write requests to the server. I figure I will return data as plain text and/or JSON. I'm debating using SQL Server or a NoSQL solution. I am also considering using something like ElasticSearch if I can't get speedy text searching working. The Microsoft topic has been somewhat confusing because I have never developed a Microsoft Web Application and most of the resources seem to assume a web based application or Azure hosting. So I was hoping for a little assurance I'm on the right track and hoping for a point in the direction to some resources that will help me on my way.

1. Microsoft Server. Not sure if I should be looking into ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WEB API, or something else entirely. If I use these frameworks, I can perform other async tasks on the machine right? For example, making additional calls to other web services to process requests.
2. Login: SSL for all connections. User sends username/password and system authentication. Server sends back token. With every request, client sends back token and server verifies token before processing request. Is this valid as long on a HTTPS connection? Just store the tokens in the server database and verify?

This application is not going to generate profit so an MBAAS is not really an option. It also is expected to handle roughly 2000 users and may need to scale to 10,000. Traffic would likely be concentrated as well. I know this is super broad, I just want a little direction to resources and big picture regarding Microsoft in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an app that will communicate with a server, you probably want a **Windows Service** (SOAP) or a **Web Service** (REST) that it can communicate with.

You don't need ASP.NET MVC or WebAPI unless you're planning on creating a website (ASP.NET MVC) and communicating from said website using HTTP requests from the client side (WebAPI).

1. A Microsoft server hosting a Windows Service or Web Service should be fine. Yes, you can perform other requests from the server, even if you're hosting websites, a web service or Windows service on the same machine.  Each HTTP request is a separate request that will be processed independently of one another.
2. Yes, you can secure the communications of between your web service and application quite easily using HTTPS/SSL.  I'm not sure about just sending an identifier back and forth and that's it, this probably wouldn't be that secure.  Maybe you can employ oAuth or a method that already exists.  I believe that if you're creating you're own security system that you're probably doing it wrong - Leave it to people that specialise in those things.